# Get network statistics on Solaris 10

Tags: networking, solaris

I am trying to get network statistics on Solaris 10.

Something like this when I was working on Linux::

```
02:42:06  IST     IFACE   rxpck/s   txpck/s    rxkB/s    txkB/s   rxcmp/s   txcmp/s  rxmcst/s
02:42:07  IST    ens192      8.00      0.00      0.52      0.00      0.00      0.00      1.00
02:42:07  IST        lo     43.00     43.00      7.98      7.98      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

The issue regarding this is that we can not expect user to install any additional packages apart from preinstalled packages.

What I have tried and the corresponding problem:

- **dladm show-dev -s**: It shows total sent and received packages. and I need per second sent and received.
- **dladm show-dev -s -i 1**: It does not stop, which can not be acceptable as the script should proceed further to index data in Splunk.
- **dlstat**: This command would do the trick, but it is not pre-installed in Solaris.

  - doubt here :: Is there a way to install dlstat on Solaris?
- **nicstat**: Not preinstalled on Solaris 10 or 11.

Is there any way to get these fields without installing any additional packages?

*Note:* Subtracting total sent and received packages manually is unreliable in this case and would not be approved further for implementation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You netstat -i perhaps suits you ?